# viewWillTransitionToSize Calls Wrong ViewController in TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller, viewwilltransitiontosize

I have tabBarController application with 4 viewcontrollers. This application is landscape orientation enabled so I have viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id)coordinator in each viewcontroller.m file to control the orientation changes.

The problem I'm having, is when I change the device orientation while in the 3rd viewcontroller, the viewWillTransitionToSize in the 2nd viewcontroller is called so the wrong code is ran.

How is it possible that the 2nd viewcontroller's viewWillTransitionToSize is even called? Especially, when it hasn't even been loaded yet. I know it hasn't been loaded because I NSLog it's viewDidLoad and it shows when I change orientation from the 3rd viewcontroller.

Additional Info: There is no code in the 3rd viewcontroller's viewWillTransitionToSize, viewWillAppear, viewWillDisappear, etc. that would reference the 2nd viewcontroller.

I'm using Xcode 8.2.1 and Objective-C code. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Try to add the relevant code (e.g. try to repoduce with the most minimal setup, maybe just 2 view controllers and a tabbar controller, no storyboards etc.)

Comment: Try to strip it down to the very minimal example that reproduces the problem and put it on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

Test to see which `UIViewController` is the selected `UIViewController` before handling the transition.

In Swift:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{
    guard self == tabBarController?.selectedViewController else { return }

    // handle transition here
}
```

In my situation, the `UIViewController` was embedded in a `UINavigationController` so I had to handle it slightly differently:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{
    guard self.navigationController == tabBarController?.selectedViewController else { return }

    // handle transition here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced each instance of

```
viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id)coordinator
```

with

```
willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

to avoid the aforementioned issue with viewWillTransitionToSize...

Comment: `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated, so that's no solution.

Comment: It gets the job done and it's not showing up as an issue on the issue navigator. I also didn't find any way to get the viewWillTransitionToSize... from triggering every viewDidLoad of each view controller it's in.